# Why aren't my fonts loading across all browsers using @font-face?

Tags: font-face, webfonts

I'm trying to use @font-face to load two fonts, but am running into all kinds of strange issues. Some browsers will load the fonts, others won't. Same browser on desktop won't load but will on mobile. I don't know if there's something wrong with my code or my file structure or what (I used fontsquirrel's generator for the sdregular font, but not the other one).

My @font-face code is:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'sdregular';
    src: url('sd-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BoereTudor';
    src: url('BOERT___0.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

My css styling code is:

```
.c9 {font-family: 'sdregular';}
.c7 {font-family: 'BoereTudor'; font-size: 1.5em;}
```

Here's the page link: https://universaltheosophy.com/hpb/voiceofthesilence.html

My stylesheets and fonts are located in the folder https://universaltheosophy.com/resources/

The css file utfonts.css calls the fonts using @font-face.
The css file utstyle.css contains the font-family setting for the two classes (.c7 and .c9)

.c7 is used for the text "Dedicated to the Few"; and .c9 is used for a symbol located here: https://universaltheosophy.com/hpb/voiceofthesilence.html#sdfootnote41sym

I've tried testing in Firefox (desktop and mobile), Chrome (desktop and mobile), and DuckDuckGo's Mobile Browser, with completely inconsistent results.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the solution, which had nothing to do with my code. My site is a wordpress site, but I'm adding these few html files separate from wordpress. The attempt to load font files from these html files resulted in a "Access-Control-Allow-Origin (CORS origin)" error. The solution is adding this little snipped of code to the wordpress .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|woff2|font.css|css|js)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Solution came from here: https://crunchify.com/how-to-fix-access-control-allow-origin-issue-for-your-https-enabled-wordpress-site-and-maxcdn/